# Group by column value when using CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

```
select C.name as Name,
       C.id as ID,         
      (CASE WHEN CA.type_id = 231 and c.id = CA.id  then CA.value end ) as PGroup,
      (CASE WHEN  CA.type_id IN ( 32, 38, 40, 52 ) and c.id = CA.id  then CA.value end )as Facilty,
      TC.cname as firmName
        from tbCases C
    join tbCompanies TC on TC.company_id = C.lawfirm_id
    join tbAttributes CA on C.case_id = CA.case_id 
    where C.client_id = 9026 and c.id = 812429
```

My Result

```
Name      ID        PGroup        Facilty     firmName
WA-SPOK   812429    NULL          SPOKANE     CUMMINGS LLP
WA-SPOK   812429    NULL          VLLEY HSP   CUMMINGS LLP
WA-SPOK   812429    Operations    NULL        CUMMINGS LLP
```

I am trying to get result like

```
Name      ID        PGroup        Facilty     firmName
WA-SPOK   812429    Operations    SPOKANE     CUMMINGS LLP
WA-SPOK   812429    Operations    VLLEY HSP   CUMMINGS LLP
```

I tried group by. How to achieve this.

Comment: The conditions for `PGroup` and `Facility` are mutually exclusive. I don't understand how meaning of the collapsed results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would benefit from some sample data, based on the query something like this could work

```
with pgroup_cte([Name], ID, firmName, PGroup) as (
    select top(1) C.[name], C.id, TC.cname,
           (CASE WHEN CA.type_id = 231 and c.id = CA.id  then CA.value end)
    from tbCases C
         join tbCompanies TC on TC.company_id = C.lawfirm_id
         join tbAttributes CA on C.case_id = CA.case_id 
    where C.client_id = 9026
          and c.id = 812429 
          and (CASE WHEN CA.type_id IN ( 32, 38, 40, 52 ) and c.id = CA.id  
                    then CA.value end) is null)
select C.[name],
       C.id,
       pc.PGroup,
      (CASE WHEN  CA.type_id IN ( 32, 38, 40, 52 ) and c.id = CA.id  then CA.value end) as Facilty,
      TC.cname as firmName
from tbCases C
     join tbCompanies TC on TC.company_id = C.lawfirm_id
     join tbAttributes CA on C.case_id = CA.case_id 
     join pgroup_cte pc on c.[Name]=pc.[Name]
                           and c.id=pc.id
                           and tc.cname=pc.firmName
where C.client_id = 9026
      and c.id = 812429 
      and (CASE WHEN CA.type_id IN ( 32, 38, 40, 52 ) and c.id = CA.id  
                then CA.value end) is not null;
```

Comment: Updated please have a look

Comment: still it is null and I have to take distinct as it is giving me error

Comment: Sorry I removed the word DISTINCT.  It wasn't needed

Comment: sorry, i meant to say even after taking distinct PGroup is null

Comment: The CTE is attempting to return only the 3rd row of your current 'My Result' rows.  Then the select statement joins that 1 row to to the first 2 rows of the 'My Result'

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to try using aggregation or pivoting by using for example **MAX()** in conjunction with the case expressions to eliminate the NULL values in the respective other columns

This will however mean aggregating your results

It is difficult to judge exactly what you want without seeing the schema of tables involved but I'll try to provide this example

Example:

```
select C.name as Name,
       C.id as ID,         
       MAX(CASE WHEN CA.type_id = 231 and c.id = CA.id  then CA.value end ) as PGroup,
       MAX(CASE WHEN  CA.type_id IN ( 32, 38, 40, 52 ) and c.id = CA.id  then CA.value end )as Facilty,
       TC.cname as firmName

    from tbCases C
    join tbCompanies TC on TC.company_id = C.lawfirm_id
    join tbAttributes CA on C.case_id = CA.case_id 
    where C.client_id = 9026 and c.id = 812429 


GROUP BY 
C.name as Name,
C.id as ID,    
TC.cname as firmName
```

Comment: Facilty has 2 values, with this query it is  just taking 1 facility value.